# Hide a folder from the URI with RewriteRule in a .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I would really appreciate if you could help me building my .htaccess file.
What I want to achieve here is moving all of my domain's files and folders to a root subfolder ("mydomain") and make sure that the URL visible to my visitors still looks like

```
domain.com/file.extention
```

instead of

```
domain.com/mydomain/file.extention
```

or

```
domain.com/subfolder/file.extention
```

instead of

```
domain.com/mydomain/subfolder/file.extention
```

This is my folders tree:

```
/
  /mydomain
    /subfolder
    index.php
    test.php
```

and here is my current .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# System symbolic links are allowed.
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Runtime rewriting engine enabled.
RewriteEngine On

#
# BEGIN DOMAIN
#

# Make 'mydomain' subfolder the root folder for the domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www\.)?domain\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^\/?$ mydomain/ [NC,L,S=1]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?mydomain/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ mydomain/$1 [NC,L]

#
# END DOMAIN
#

</IfModule>
```

The problem here is that it works when I browse for

```
domain.com/subfolder/
```

but not with

```
domain.com/subfolder
```

and with

```
domain.com/index.php
```

but not with

```
domain.com/test.php
```

Thank you all,
Matteo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing domain.com/mydomain/file.extention to domain.com/file.extention

use this for example

```
RewriteRule ^mydomain/(.+)$ http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

But if you redirects working just for some pages check that you clear browser cache or use another one instead

Comment: The no-cached pages trick worked fine. I no longer see any discrepancies between domain.com/index.php and domain.com/test.php. Thank you.
I am also thinking of adding a rule to automatically add a slash if !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$ && !/$ . This should solve the problem with domain.com/subfolder